# Given URL works in the browser but not in the web view android

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio, webview

In manifest network access is given. I have a web view inside an activity class, it works if I use the intent thing and prompt the user with the mobile browser.

But when I try to load it inside the web  view it does not load.

Any help, here goes the code:

```
public class DirectToWebActivity extends Activity {

  private WebView webView;
  private String url = "https://m.sportsbet.com.au";

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
      webView  = new WebView(this);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      final Activity activity = this;
      webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
             //todo
        }
    });

      webView .loadUrl(url);
      setContentView(webView);

  }
}
```

Comment: did you add the internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes it the first thing i mentioned in the question

Comment: @SisaraRanasinghe ...try  my solution below.. and plz let me know in case of concern

Comment: @Ravindra Kushwaha .. still the same that page displays like loading and thats all. Can there be any link with the page size when it loads to the mobile or the link because if i try with a link like www.google.com it works 

but if i use the mobile browser to go the url that i need it works :(

Comment: @Let me try these....soon i will post the solution

Comment: @ Ravindra Kushwaha - the issue comes with the link for sure because i added the ebay site link and it works 

then i tried to webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false); to the real link it doesnt work yet can you point out any issue with that link ?

Comment: but if i use it as and intent it loads but that's not i want :(

Comment: @SisaraRanasinghe ...Brother it is working fine in my device....plz check again my solution....Did u try my code...the below code i have used with your URL...and it is wirking fine...without any problem,,,plz check at your end

Comment: ok i ll give it a shot

Comment: @ Ravindra Kushwaha - brother does it go more than loading? or is it just stay like saying loading?

Comment: it open successfully the URL's web site.....but loader below the 'sportbet' is still loading...

Comment: yup brother thats the issue :( only loading .. but if we use intent and call the link with the browser it loads

Comment: try {
                    String url = "URL";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("webAddressTextViewClick" + e);
                    
                }


like this in oncreate it works but not what i want

Comment: ok..i got...where have you stuck....let me try again

Comment: i guess its a issue of the link right . i am not good about web .. so dumb question .. can web view affect with the way that page designed  i mean the language or the stuff

Comment: any way thanks  brother for helping :)

Comment: @SisaraRanasinghe ...Yes bro..there is issue in the link....like i am getting these error===== "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://m.sportsbet.com.au/require-1450050935904.js  .........................When u will add "p" at the last of the LINK..than there will open the website....but when u will hit the same link u will get the error....So we can not any thing in it.....

Comment: Ravindra Kushwaha - thanks brother you helped me a lot at least i got the idea yes and thanks if i get any clue more than you i will post here :)

Comment: bother can you give and example of that "p thing here i didn't get it

Comment: when i will add the "p" at the last f link in my above comments it make makes page like "JSP"...and able to view...But i am getting exception while running program like     "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: m.sportsbet.com.au/require-1450050935904.js............Therefore it loading continuosly on the device bro ...........If it is helpful for you...than plz bro accept it for other people who may also will stuck in the future ..

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines of code for it

```
long delayInMillis = 10000;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // show progress bar here until the web view is not loaded
        }
    }, delayInMillis);

   /////FIND THE WEB VIEW ID FROM THE LAYOUT LIKE BELOW

    WebView webview = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("PASTE YOUR URL HERE");
```

Comment: when i will add the "p" at the last f link in my above comments it make makes page like "JSP"...and able to view...But i am getting exception while running program like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: m.sportsbet.com.au/require-1450050935904.js............Therefore it loading continuosly on the device bro ...........

Comment: @SisaraRanasinghe If it is helpful for you...than plz bro accept it for other people who may also will stuck in the future